# Help me understand this function title. Code from FreeBSD 8 source code UFS part

Tags: c, unix, kernel, freebsd

```
 /*
  180  * Create a regular file
  181  */
  182 static int
  183 ufs_create(ap)
  184         struct vop_create_args /* {
  185                 struct vnode *a_dvp;
  186                 struct vnode **a_vpp;
  187                 struct componentname *a_cnp;
  188                 struct vattr *a_vap;
  189         } */ *ap;
  190 {
  191         int error;
  192 
  193         error =
  194             ufs_makeinode(MAKEIMODE(ap->a_vap->va_type, ap->a_vap->va_mode),
  195             ap->a_dvp, ap->a_vpp, ap->a_cnp);
  196         if (error)
  197                 return (error);
  198         return (0);
  199 }
```

Please help me to get information from line 182-189...this is strange for me.. What is this function title means? (I mean, what is return value, what is input parameter?)
Thank you all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return type is `int` and it takes one argument, a `struct vop_create_args*` named `ap`. This is K&R notation.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old-style (pre-prototype) function declaration. The function is local to the current translation unit, returns an `int`, `ap` is the parameter it accepts and it's of the type:

```
struct vop_create_args *
```

All that other stuff is just comments, presumably echoing the *actual* definition of the structure so that the information is held locally as well (so a lazy coder doesn't have to go looking for it, a somewhat dangerous practice if the actual and local definitions get out of step).

It's equivalent to:

```
static int ufs_create (struct vop_create_args *ap) { ...
```